# Two interview questions

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, combinatorial-proofs

I recently came across two interview questions for admission in B.Math at an university. I gave the two questions a try and want to know if my solutions are correct or not.

**Q1:** Given that $x^4-4x^3+ax^2+bx+1=0$ has all positive roots and $a,b\in\Bbb R$, prove that all the roots are equal.

**My solution:** Let $p,q,r,s$ be the four roots of the given equation. Using Vieta's formulas, we have,

$$p+q+r+s=4\quad\textrm{and}\quad pqrs=1$$

Since $p,q,r,s$ are all positive, we have, by the AM-GM inequality,

$$\frac{p+q+r+s}{4}\geq\sqrt[4]{pqrs}=\sqrt[4]{1}=1\implies p+q+r+s\geq 4$$

Since we got $p+q+r+s=4$ using Vieta's formulas and knowing that the equality case in AM-GM inequality holds iff $p=q=r=s$, we conclude that all the roots to the given equation are equal. $_\square$

---

**Q2:** Without actually computing anything, find the value of $\dbinom{p+q}2-\dbinom p2-\dbinom q2$.

**My solution:** Since it's told not to actually compute anything, I suppose that they were asking for a combinatorial proof. I have the following argument:

Suppose we have $p+q$ people in a room with $p$ people in Group 1 and $q$ people in Group 2. Then, $\dbinom{p+q}2$ counts the number of ways we can select two people from the people in the entire room. However, $\dbinom p2$ and $\dbinom q2$ count the number of ways we can select two people from Group 1 and Group 2 respectively.

Now, we can select two people from the entire room by either taking two people from Group 1 or taking two people from Group 1 or taking one person from Group 1 and another from Group 2. These are the only possible methods.

So, the expression we have counts the number of ways we can select one person from Group 1 containing $p$ people and another person from Group 2 containing $q$ people. By the rule of product, we have $pq$ ways to do this and hence the value of the given expression is $pq$. $_\square$

Comment: Yes, this is excellent.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to ask what kind of a B. Math programme that is, since it assumes that applicants already know a great deal of mathematics?

Comment: @sequence, AFAIK, these questions are from the interview for the B.Math programme at [ISI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Statistical_Institute) (I got them from a thread on Quora)

Comment: Wow, that must be a very strong university. I don't think even MIT requires that level of knowledge of pure mathematics. Students only begin to learn the foundations there. Are Indian high schools that strong?

Comment: ISI usually asks questions of higher difficulty than this. Last year, my senior was asked to find sum of reciprocals of the 3rd powers of the roots of a cubic $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. It took nearly 10 minutes for me to solve, which is a long time given that I was not under the stress of the interview at that time.

Comment: @ShankRam, is the answer $\dfrac{b^2}{d^3}(b-3d)$ ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. It is to find $\sum \frac{1}{\alpha ^3}$

Comment: It was my fault really. I didn't mention the question properly.

Comment: So can u suggest me any link to interveiw questions asked in ISI?! I gave the subjective and hoping to qualify it....

Comment: @sequence I have studied in India all my life and had Math throughout my school life. I am also much better than most people at Math..1) As far as question 1 posted by the OP is concerned, not even very good math students in India who have just passed school will be able to solve it . We are taught calculus,trigonometry, progressions, quadratic equations, etc at school but we are not taught how to solve this kind of a question where vieta's formula is needed. Contd. below

Comment: However, students who take Math in their final 2 years in school are taught combinations and permutations. And thus, they have all the knowledge they need to solve question 2. But note that question 2 asks that you solve it without computing anything. And this can only be done by a handful of students in India who have just finished school even if they had Math in their last 2 years of schooling.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal Thanks for clarifying this. So is the point then to narrow down the selection of students due to a relatively large number of them?

Comment: IISc Bangalore is a very prestigious university..and India has a huge population and many students take extensive coaching in their last 2 years of school to get into the best engineering schools. So, I would guess yes ..questions at IISc would be do tough to narrow down the pool of eligible students.

Answer (score 2):

Citing the number of upvotes on Brian M. Scott's comment, I believe it's safe to say your answers are correct. I would just like to officially answer this question to remove it from the *Unanswered Questions* queue.